# VC++ CLI/CLR, winforms combobox bind datasource to enum

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, enums, datasource

I have an enum like this

```
enum class distance 

    {ten=10,twenty=20};
```

and a combobox whose datasource is binded to this enum as:

```
this->comboBox1->DataSource=Enum::GetValues(distance::typeid)
```

I expected the above to return 10,20 but instead I get ten, twenty.

**How to show values instead of names in combobox?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: you want the integral values, not the names.  That still requires Enum::GetValues() to obtain the enumerated values but they have to be cast to int so that the ToString() override doesn't generate the name.  Make that look like this:

```
        enum class distance {ten=10,twenty=20};

        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Array^ values = Enum::GetValues(distance::typeid);
            array<int>^ display = gcnew array<int>(values->Length);
            for (int ix = 0; ix < values->Length; ++ix) {
                display[ix] = (int)values->GetValue(ix);
            }
            comboBox1->DataSource = display;
        }
```

Where Form1(void) is the constructor of your form class.

Comment: GetNames also gives the same result

Comment: Of course it is not possible to get the same result.  It worked just fine when I tried it, the combo box dropdown was filled with the strings, not the numbers.  I cannot guess why it doesn't work when you try this, update your question with the code you tried.

Comment: My code is up there. GetNames gives me names of string ten, twenty, and so does GetValues(distance::typeid) I wan the values 10,20 in my dropdownbox and not names But GetValues is also giving me names

Comment: How can set the selectedVAlue or selectedItem in this combobox?